# Autowire on new-ing up an object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, autowired

I've a scenario where a bean I'm using has some fields populated from properties file while others need to be populated dynamically (from a api call). 
Here is my bean:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="studio")
public class Studio {

   private String areaCode; // loads from application.properties

   private String hours; // loads from application.properties

   private String groupCode; // loads from application.properties

   private Address address; // loads from a api

   private String id; // loads from a api

   public Studio(String id, String city, String subdivision,
            String addressLine1, String postalCode) {

         Address address = Address.builder()
               .street(addressLine1)
               .city(city)
               .postalCode(postalCode)
               .state(subdivision)
               .build();
     this.id = id;
         this.address = address;
   }

 }
```

Now the method that populates the dynamic fields is like this:

```
 private List<Studio> getStudioDataFromApi(ResponseEntity<String> exchange)
       throws Exception {

    List<Studio> infoList = $(exchange.getBody())
          .xpath("Area[TypeCode=\"CA\"]")
          .map(
          Area -> new Studio(
                $(Area).child("Id").text(String.class), 
                $(Area).child("Address").child("City").text(String.class), 
                $(Area).child("Address").child("Subdivision").text(String.class), 
                $(Area).child("Address").child("AddressLine1").text(String.class), 
                $(Area).child("Address").child("PostalCode").text(String.class))
          );
    return infoList;
}
```

I Autowire Studio in that class. Now whenever I run this, I get the fields that are populated from the properties file as null. I can see the reason, which is, new doesn't know anything about the autowired bean. My question is how can I use both? i.e. use a bean that has always some fields populated from a config when its new-ed up. 
Context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

      <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
      <bean id="ItemReader" class="com.sdm.studio.reader.StudioReader" scope="step">
           <property name="studio" ref="Studio" />
      </bean>     
      <bean id="Studio" class="com.sdm.studio.domain.Studio" />     
</bean>
```

Comment: I would start by  separating your Studio class into two classes.  One class should be a ConfigurationProperties class for holding configuration data. The other could be a regular bean where you could Autowire dependencies such as Studio

Comment: @Gary then what's the best way to combine them ? I need to send all those fields to an external api

Answer (score 1):

[edit: full code example shown here is also on [github](https://github.com/gclayburg/springboot-javaconfig-xml) ]

Try this:

```
//This class contains read-only properties, loaded from Spring Externalized Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="studio") 
public class Studio {

    private String areacode; // loads from application.properties

    //... also add other read-only properties and getters/setters...

    public String getAreacode() {
        return areacode;
    }

    public Studio setAreacode(String areacode) {
        this.areacode = areacode;
        return this;
    }

}

//Just a POJO
class FullStudio {
    private String id;
    private Address address;

    FullStudio(String id, String city, String areaCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = new Address(id, city, areaCode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FullStudio{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }
}
class Address{
    String id;
    String city;
    String areaCode;

    public Address(String id, String city, String areaCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", areaCode='" + areaCode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

What we are doing here is allowing Spring to control the lifecycle of the Studio class.  You don't need to create a new Studio yourself.  Spring does that when it starts up.  Since it is also a `@ConfigurationProperties` class it will also populate values from Spring [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)  Note: you also need public getters and setters so that Spring can populate the values for you.

`FullStudio` is not a Spring managed class.  You create your own `FullStudio` with values from Studio and any other api.

And here is a class that is not configured with Java Config `@Configuration` but instead is managed by an xml configuration:

```
public class StudioReader {

    private Studio wiredstudio;

    public String getMessage(){
        return wiredstudio.getAreacode();
    }

    public StudioReader setWiredstudio(Studio studio) {
        this.wiredstudio = studio;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And we use this `mycontext.xml` file to create this bean with the reference to `wiredstudio`.  The `Studio` that Spring wires in here comes from our Studio instance configured with JavaConfig.  The `ref` attribute of `studio` is the name that Spring automatically chose for us based on the name of the `Studio` class when it instantiated it into our spring application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="studioReaderReader" class="com.example.StudioReader" >
        <property name="wiredstudio" ref="studio" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Personally, I think it is more trouble than its worth for new projects to combine xml and Java Configuration for Spring beans, but it can be done.

Here is a test class that shows how our Studio class can be used from classes created with Spring Java Config and XML config:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class StartAppTest {

    @Autowired private Studio studio;
    @Autowired private StudioReader studioReader;

    @Test
    public void contextok() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void fullStudio() throws Exception {
        FullStudio fs = new FullStudio("1", "Denver", studio.getAreacode());
        System.out.println("stdio is: " + fs);
        assertEquals("303", studio.getAreacode());
    }

    @Test
    public void loadstudioreader() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("303",studioReader.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In order to run this test, you will need 2 more files:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:mycontext.xml")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and our application.properties file:

```
studio.areacode=303
```

Comment: somehow this is not working for main java classes - interesting part is the test is passing but when I use in class (under main java ) where I autowire Studio, its throwing NPE - the class is defined in context-bean.xml

Comment: Oh I see.  You are mixing Spring XML configuration with Java Config.  The example I posted only uses JavaConfig.  I find things are simpler that way if you just use one method of configuration.  [There are ways you can mix the two so that beans you define in the xml file can see the JavaConfig beans](http://memorynotfound.com/mixing-xml-java-config-spring/)

Comment: thx Gary - I'll look into it - and completely agree - however is there a way to use your example in my scenario? i.e. using XML config?

Comment: can you post your xml file?  Are you doing component scanning in your xml file?

Comment: added it in the question